# Finding an inverse using the square and multiply algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

> Given $7^{45}\equiv32 \bmod 101$, find $32^{-1}$ using square and multiply.

What I did was since $(7^{45})^{-1}$ is equal to $(32)^{-1}$, and $-45\bmod 101 = 56$ then $32^{-1} = 7^{56}$. I then used square and multiply but I get $16$ for $7^{56}$ but I know that the inverse of $32$ modulo $101$ is $60$.

Am I missing a property of square and multiply or of modular arithmetic for this not to work?

Comment: You are  not applying Fermat"s Little Theorem correctly.  Since $101$ is prime, you should reduce exponents mod $100$.

Comment: we have $7^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod {101}$ so you should be looking at $7^{55}$ not $7^{60}$.

Comment: @hardmath so whenever reducing exponents in prime mod spaces you reduce them by $\bmod (p-1)$ instead of $\bmod p$?

Comment: Right, so the power $-1$ (multiplicative inverse) amounts to the power $p-2$ regarding prime modulus $p$.  Euler worked out what the rule for a composite modulus has to be.

Answer (score 1):

People have pointed you to the right direction. I'll just do it here for my own sake. Everything below is $\pmod{101}$.

$$
32^{-1}\equiv 7^{55}\equiv 108^{55}\equiv (2^2 \cdot 3^3)^{55}\equiv 2^{110} \cdot 3^{165} \equiv 2^{10} \cdot 3^{65} \equiv 2^{10} \cdot 3 \cdot (81)^{16} \\
\equiv 2^{10} \cdot 3 \cdot (-20)^{16} \equiv 2^{10} \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{16} \cdot 10^{16} \equiv 2^{26} \cdot 3 \cdot 100^8 \equiv \frac{(2^9)^3 \cdot 3}{2}\\
\equiv \frac{512^3}{2}\cdot 3 \equiv \frac{7^3}{2} \cdot 3 \equiv \frac{343}{2}3 \equiv \frac{40}{2}\cdot 3 \equiv 60.
$$